# Today's Button in bsDatepicker

Tags: button, datepicker

Can we have a Today button on the calendar so that when we click the button, reset the calendar to Today's date?

I am following this tutorial https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#config-object

Comment: Could you provide what you have done so far? It seems like you are asking us to write your code for you. See [ask] and [mcve] and maybe take the [tour] if you haven't already.

Comment: I have import as:  import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; It gives me good calendar datepicker. There is no Today button on it by default. Is there a way, we can have datepicker with today button too.

Comment: Do you need the today button added to the datepicker, or could it be separate from it?

Comment: I want the "Today" button added to the datepicker

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">

      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             [(ngModel)]="bsValue"
             #dp="bsDatepicker"
             bsDatepicker
             [bsValue]="bsValue"
             [bsConfig]="bsConfig"
             (ngModelChange)="emitSelectedDate()">

      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button" [attr.aria-expanded]="dp.isOpen">

      </button>
```

---

In component

I import as import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

and below code

```
bsValue = new Date();
  selectedDate: any;

  bsConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig> ;


  constructor() { 
    this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { containerClass: this.colorTheme });
    this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { showWeekNumbers: false }); 
    // this.bsConfig = Object.assign({}, { todayBtn: true }); 

 }
```

I tried to put TodayBtn as true but there is no such property. I got a nice calendar but want to have a button "Today" on the calendar which will reset the calendar to todays date.

Answer (score 1):

I have fix this requirement, you can check this live example on 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-date-picker-add-custom-content

ngx-bootstrap doesn't provide any facility to add custom content in date-picker pop-up. But we can dynamically add content into it and after adding i have used RxJS fromEvent method to populate event. Once we got clicked event we can add logic our into it.

Here I have added three sample button they are Today, Reset and Close button for your reference.

Do click on Today button to get your answer.